# Answering the assumed question over the immediate question

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

Today I went about answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30379909/java-util-concurrentmodificationexception-error-when-refer-to-arraylist-of-array) on `ConcurrentModicationException` whilst mutating a list in an enhanced for-loop and suggested the OP to use `ListIterator`'s add() method instead, posting a proposed solution **mirroring the OP's code** but with enhanced for replaced with valid code.

To my dismay I received a downvote for offering a proposed solution. In Luiggi Mendoza (the presumed downvoter)'s words: "Explanation of the problem is ok (more verbose that Jon Skeet's, but is ok). Proposed solution is not."

After having an comment discussion with Luiggi he suggested my proposed answer is invalid because it doesn't solve the (assumed) overall problem that the OP is having with his/her code. Furthermore, Luiggi stated that since an existing question (this one was marked duplicate) already has solutions to the immediate problem, my solution is invalid.

I know I'm probably in the wrong of attempting to answer the question despite knowing with good certainty there is an duplicate but I believe that:

1. Answerers shouldn't assume details about the OP's intended code if it isn't completely necessary.
2. Answerers should fix or attempt to explain why the OP's code isn't working (providing the question is up to SO standards) **without** regard of actual overall functionality (again, if not necessary)

I understand cases where the OP has made his/her intention clear but their code doesn't fully satisfy what they need, an answer can offer a completely different solution **with** explanation why the OP's original code won't work. But in this case, the OP asked directly about a specific issue in which I answered without consideration of the overall function of the program.

To summarize, from my perspective, answerers shouldn't be assuming things about the OP's code if they aren't critical to the OP's immediate problem even if the code seems trivially incorrect with respect to an assumed function. Luiggi's perspective is that the answer (or my answer at least) should fix the OP's assumed overall problem, disregarding the immediate issue **because there exists duplicates that answer the immediate issue**.

Comment: For a [certain class of questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), answering it literally and not taking a step back and considering the broader picture is a cruel punishment - but not that unusual. It mostly depends on my mood how far I go in answering these.

Comment: @Jongware Of course, on the flip side, trying to guess at what someone wants when they really do know what they want and are asking for it can also be cruel.  It's why this whole thing is a judgement call and not a simple "always do this".  And of course people may disagree on what an author might actually want to do, what they actually asked for, and which of the two should actually be answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both value systems that you've described are valid.  If you want to strive to always answer questions based on the literal question asked, and evaluate answers to questions you see based on how well they answer the question asked, rather than how well they address what you feel is the actual problem not actually asked, that's perfectly fine.

Likewise, if someone else choose to consider not just what the question actually asks, but what they think readers would actually want to see, when evaluating other answers or writing their own, that is *also* acceptable.

People should be voting based on whether or not they consider an answer to be "useful".  What "useful" means is *intentionally* left vague an open to the interpretation of the reader.  If you think that it's useful to answer the question actually asked, rather than what you think the OP might have intended to ask, more power to you.  If someone else things that it's more useful to attempt to answer the question that the author *intended* to ask, regardless of what they *actually* asked, that is also their choice.

In my own personal evaluations of posts I tend to use a combination of the two in determining the usefulness of a post, without universally sticking to one system or the other.  Both viewpoints have their merits and their drawbacks, along with all of the other infinitely different ways people evaluate the usefulness of posts.